# JLanguageTool do not ignore digits in words

Tags: java, numbers, tokenize, digits, languagetool

I'm using JLanguageTool with the German language (`de-DE`) for spellchecking and noticed that digits seems to be used as a word separator (just like spaces?). For example `We8lt` is not reported as a single incorrect word but as two spelling erros (one for `We` and one for `lt`). Or for example `bis8` is not reported as an error at all.

Example call (I'm using it as a Java library but the behaviour is the same):

```
$ echo "Hallo We8lt bis8 Test" | java -jar languagetool-commandline.jar -l de-DE -
Expected text language: German (Germany)
Working on STDIN...

1.) Line 1, column 7, Rule ID: GERMAN_SPELLER_RULE prio=-3
Message: Möglicher Tippfehler gefunden.
Suggestion: WE; Der; Den; Des; Dem
Hallo We8lt bis8 Test 
      ^^              

2.) Line 1, column 10, Rule ID: GERMAN_SPELLER_RULE prio=-3
Message: Möglicher Tippfehler gefunden.
Suggestion: LT; als; lag; alt; elf
Hallo We8lt bis8 Test 
         ^^           

Time: 1618ms for 1 sentences (0.6 sentences/sec)
```

This is a big problem for as as for example missing spaces between words and numbers are not found. How can I get the library/tool to do not treat numbers as word separators? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right: LanguageTool treats numbers as word separators in German.

To modify this behaviour, you have to change the source code and change [this line in GermanSpellerRule.java](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/e6daa54d4b42f731462b796d4094a1dd3df8ef66/languagetool-language-modules/de/src/main/java/org/languagetool/rules/de/GermanSpellerRule.java#L1072) from

```
String pattern = "(" + nonWordPattern.pattern() + "|(?<=[\\d°])-|-(?=\\d+))";
```

to

```
String pattern = ("(" + nonWordPattern.pattern() + "|(?<=[\\d°])-|-(?=\\d+))").replace("{L}", "{L}\\d");
```

Alternatively, you could add another rule to [grammar.xml](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-language-modules/de/src/main/resources/org/languagetool/rules/de/grammar.xml) which complains about missing spaces before/after numbers:

```
<rule id="RULE" name="rule">
<pattern>
    <token regexp="yes">[a-zäöüß]+\d+[a-zäöüß]*</token>
</pattern>
<message>Fehlt hier ein Leerzeichen?</message>
<example correction=""><marker>P4sswort</marker>.</example>
```

[image: Ruleeditor]